# Microsoft Excel Format

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have set up an excel file with 10 sheets with conditional formatting on all to change fill colour and text colour if i start with the letter "A" in a cell for example to red fill colour and white text.

Is there a way to have the colour as an option somewhere, either a formula or a way to copy the conditional format from a cell somewhere on another sheet somewhere so if someone wanted to make "A" a different fill (for example brown) colour they could input that easily somewhere and then would carry across to all sheets?

Comment: no, there is no easy way for that. You can do it with a macro, but that probably requires a lot of coding.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't really do coding, could do it with a little bit of help but hoping for an easier solution

Comment: If anyone else is having the same dilemma by chance.
I found an acceptable solution which is just making the conditional formatting on the first page and then copying the cell and doing a special paste to all other sheets which worked